# Is their ay way for Rally automatic login using url?

Tags: rally, autologin, remote-login

I want the user to get login to rally application using URL
- might be passing user credentials using url 
- sending authentication header info

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Are you just trying to write an integration using the Webservices API?

Comment: I am looking a way to make user login when they go to the certain URL using certain parameters.

Comment: I don't think that is supported.  You may be able to reach out to support to confirm...